# How the ledger is kept consistent among different peers in a blockchain system

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

In a blockchain system like bitcoin, each peer (participate node) keeps a full copy of the ledger. A peer updates its copy of ledger when it receives and validates a newly arrived block. However, the peers are scattered around the globe, and the network latency among these peers varies a lot. Therefore, how the blockchain system guarantees that all the peers have finished updating their copies of ledger after a block has been propagated?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin doesn't guarantee that all ledgers become updated at the same time, bitcoin blockchain provides you with consistent ledger following:

1. Proof-of-work to cut new block with set of transactions
2. Longest chain rule

Above guaranties you that if there no more than 51% of the network controlled by one group you will eventually see consistent ledger, e.g. given your ledger at block sequence number 1001 means all nodes in the network will see identical chain of blocks until 1001.

To your question bitcoins use random overlay network to distribute new blocks (pretty similar to gossip algorithm).

---

**UPDATE**

See section *B.  Propagation Method* from [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/deb1/c04f3584a59b489e9582b244c10c7f9b20cf.pdf):

> For  the  purpose  of  updating  and  synchronizing  the  ledger
>   replicas  only  transaction  (
>   tx
>   )  and  block  (
>   block
>   )  messages  are
>   relevant. These messages are far more common than any other
>   message sent on the network and may grow to a considerable
>   size. In order to avoid sending transaction and block messages
>   to nodes that already received them from other nodes, they are
>   not forwarded directly. Instead their availability is announced
>   to  the  neighbors  by  sending  them  an
>   inv
>   message  once  the
>   transaction  or  block  has  been  completely  verified.  The  inv
>   message contains a set of transaction hashes and block hashes
>   that  have  been  received  by  the  sender  and  are  now  available
>   to  be  requested.  A  node,  receiving  an  inv  message  for  a
>   transaction or block that it does not yet have locally, will issue
>   a
>   getdata
>   message to the sender of the inv message containing
>   the hashes of the information it needs. The actual transfer of the  block  or  transaction  is  done  via  individual  block  or  tx
>   messages.  Figure  2  visualizes  the  protocol  flow  for  a  single
>   hop in the broadcast.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Barger. So my understanding is that (1) For a peer, in order to verify a newly received transaction or block, it does not need to refer to any information in the blockchain. Verification is just to verify the signature in a transaction or a block. (2)  If a the current block head(B) height in a peer's ledger is H, but this peer receives a new block (B') with height H+10, then the peer will proactive ask its neighbors for all the blocks between B and B' before adding B' to its ledger. Correct?

Comment: Because of the longest chain rules there is a general advise to wait for 6 next blocks to be sure you picked the right chain, and yes block with sequence number H+10 won't be applied to the ledger which current height is H (while not sure about proactively asking part).

Comment: What if a block got lost on a peer, how this peer will response?

Comment: What do you mean by block go lost on the peer? Peer is missing the block? So it will try to replicated from the peer in the network which advertised availability of that block. If you trying to retrieve block number X, while it missing, I'd guess you will get an error :).

Comment: Just think of it as a block on a peer got deleted for whatever reason. Does a peer needs to refer to the existing blocks in the blockchain in order to validate a newly arrived transaction? If not, how does a peer detect that a block has been deleted (missing)?

Comment: Let's start from the the fact that blockchain is append only ledger, hence you cannot delete a block from it. And block has to point on the hash of the previous one, this is how they chained together.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But what if a peer node has been compromised, and a block is then deleted by the attacker. Since a block is just a piece of disk data, it can be wiped out anyway. Then the hacker is killed, so the peer node will continue to operate with a block missing. My question is will this peer be able to detect that a block is missing in its copy of ledger?

Comment: You can scan your ledger from the end point to the genesis block, validating hash chain to see if you missed something. Each block has a has of the previous one, so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sure, then my question is that in which case this missing block will be detected by the peer? I am thinking that when the peer validates a newly received transaction, it will need to refer to all the historical related transactions, then if one of such historical transactions is in that missing block, the peer then detects that a block is missing. But I am not sure whether my understanding is correct, please advise.

Comment: Here is the checklist of actions: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules#.22block.22_messages